# Android Take Screenshot of Surface View Shows Black Screen

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am attempting to Take a Screenshot of my Game through code and Share it through an Intent. I able to do of those things, however the screenshot always appears black. Here is the Code Related to Sharing the Screenshot:

```
View view = MainActivity.getView();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(true));
.. save Bitmap
```

This is in the MainActivity:

```
view = new GameView(this);
view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

public static SurfaceView getView() {
    return view;
}
```

And the View itself:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
...etc
```

And this is how I am Drawing everything:

```
Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        if (canvas != null) {
                Game.draw(canvas);
...
```

Ok, based on some answers, i have constructed this:

```
public static void share() {
    Bitmap screen = GameView.SavePixels(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = c.getTime();
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(
            Game.context.getContentResolver(), screen, "screenShotBJ" + d
                    + ".png", null);
    System.out.println(path + " PATH");
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    Game.context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
            "Share High Score:"));
}
```

The Gameview contains the Following Method:

```
public static Bitmap SavePixels(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
    GL10 gl = (GL10) egl.eglGetCurrentContext().getGL();
    int b[] = new int[w * (y + h)];
    int bt[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.wrap(b);
    ib.position(0);
    gl.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y + h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < h; i++, k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            int pix = b[i * w + j];
            int pb = (pix >> 16) & 0xff;
            int pr = (pix << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
            int pix1 = (pix & 0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
            bt[(h - k - 1) * w + j] = pix1;
        }
    }

    Bitmap sb = Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    return sb;
}
```

The Screenshot is still Black. Is there something wrong with the way I am saving it perhaps?

I have attempted several different methods to take the Screenshot, but none of them worked:
The one shown in the code above was the most commonly suggested one. But it does not seem to work.
Is this an Issue with using SurfaceView? And if so, why does view.getDrawingCache(true) even exist if I cant use it and how do I fix this?

My code:

```
public static void share() {
    // GIVES BLACK SCREENSHOT:
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = c.getTime();

    Game.update();
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(Screen.width, Screen.height, conf);
    Canvas canvas = GameThread.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
    canvas.setBitmap(image);
    Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setARGB(255, 40, 40, 40);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),
            backgroundPaint);
    Game.draw(canvas);
    Bitmap screen = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, Screen.width,
            Screen.height);
    canvas.setBitmap(null);
    GameThread.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(
            Game.context.getContentResolver(), screen, "screenShotBJ" + d
                    + ".png", null);
    System.out.println(path + " PATH");
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    Game.context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
            "Share High Score:"));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: My Code is based on the Accepted answer on that Post. Still not working

Comment: Click  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651242/4419437) for Answer.it will give help you :)

Comment: @TastyLemons Pls remove the words "WORKING CODE:". It misguides readers.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There is a great deal of confusion about this, and a few [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486164/how-to-take-snapshot-of-surfaceview/27488970#27488970) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086263/take-screenshot-of-surfaceview/25086739#25086739).

Here's the deal:

1. A SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  The Surface is on a completely separate layer from all of the View UI elements.  The `getDrawingCache()` approach works on the View layer only, so it doesn't capture anything on the Surface.
2. The buffer queue has a producer-consumer API, and it can have only one producer.  Canvas is one producer, GLES is another.  You can't draw with Canvas and read pixels with GLES.  (Technically, you *could* if the Canvas were using GLES and the correct EGL context was current when you went to read the pixels, but that's not guaranteed.  Canvas rendering to a Surface is not accelerated in any released version of Android, so right now there's no hope of it working.)
3. (Not relevant for your case, but I'll mention it for completeness:) A Surface is not a frame buffer, it is a queue of buffers.  When you submit a buffer with GLES, it is gone, and you can no longer read from it.  So if you were rendering with GLES and capturing with GLES, you would need to read the pixels back before calling `eglSwapBuffers()`.

With Canvas rendering, the easiest way to "capture" the Surface contents is to simply draw it twice.  Create a screen-sized Bitmap, create a Canvas from the Bitmap, and pass it to your `draw()` function.

With GLES rendering, you can use `glReadPixels()` before the buffer swap to grab the pixels.  There's a (less-expensive than the code in the question) implementation of the grab code in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika); see `saveFrame()` in [EglSurfaceBase](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java).

If you were sending video directly to a Surface (via MediaPlayer) there would be no way to capture the frames, because your app never has access to them -- they go directly from mediaserver to the compositor (SurfaceFlinger).  You can, however, route the incoming frames through a SurfaceTexture, and render them twice from your app, once for display and once for capture.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486164/how-to-take-snapshot-of-surfaceview/) for more info.

One alternative is to replace the SurfaceView with a TextureView, which can be drawn on like any other Surface.  You can then use one of the [`getBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap()) calls to capture a frame.  TextureView is less efficient than SurfaceView, so this is not recommended for all situations, but it's straightforward to do.

If you were hoping to get a composite screen shot containing both the Surface contents and the View UI contents, you will need to capture the Canvas as above, capture the View with the usual drawing cache trick, and then composite the two manually.  Note this won't pick up the system parts (status bar, nav bar).

**Update:** on Lollipop and later (API 21+) you can use the [MediaProjection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) class to capture the entire screen with a virtual display.  There are some trade-offs with this approach, e.g. you're capturing the rendered screen, not the frame that was sent to the Surface, so what you get may have been up- or down-scaled to fit the window. In addition, this approach involves an Activity switch since you have to create an intent (by calling createScreenCaptureIntent on the ProjectionManager object) and wait for its result.

If you want to learn more about how all this stuff works, see the Android [System-Level Graphics Architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) doc.

Comment: So just to Clarify, How exactly do I Store the Canvas into a Bitmap?

Comment: You create a Bitmap, then pass it to the Canvas constructor -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)

Comment: I have a relative layout under which there is a surface view which has the camera calling and on top of it there is a imageview which augments the camera. How to I take a screenshot of this whole scenario?

Comment: @navinpai please ask questions by creating a new question, not adding a comment to an answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545970/take-a-screenshot-using-mediaprojection

Comment: so how to take the damn screenshot given an activity root view

Comment: Hello @fadden will [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) api help here?

Answer (score 11):

I know its a late reply but for those who face the same problem,

we can use **PixelCopy** for fetching the snapshot. It's available in `API level 24` and above

```
PixelCopy.request(surfaceViewObject,BitmapDest,listener,new Handler());
```

where,

**surfaceViewObject is the object of surface view**

**BitmapDest is the bitmap object where the image will be saved and it cant be null**

**listener is OnPixelCopyFinishedListener**

for more info refer - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for something similar which works pre-24?

Comment: nope, I tried a lot of solutions but in the case of a surface view, only this works.

Comment: So this will work for a single Surface view ? What if the display currently is composed of a surface view and normal Android UI layer ?

Comment: this is only for the surface view, I haven't that scenario for the surface view and other contents.

Comment: @AnjaniMittal There is an new api added in level 26, which you can capture a window, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy.html#request(android.view.Window,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.view.PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener,%20android.os.Handler)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the complete method to take screen shot of a surface view using [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy). It requires API 24(Android N).

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void capturePicture() {
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    PixelCopy.request(surfaceView, bmp, i -> {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp); //"iv_Result" is the image view
    }, new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2020 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) is deprecated in API 28

**If you are using normal View** then you can create a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into. Then ask the view to draw over that canvas and return bitmap filled by Canvas

```
 /**
     * Copy View to Canvas and return bitMap
     */
    fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
```

Or you can fill the canvas with a default color before drawing it with the view:

```
    /**
     * Copy View to Canvas and return bitMap and fill it with default color
     */
    fun getBitmapFromView(view: View, defaultColor: Int): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        var canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        canvas.drawColor(defaultColor)
        view.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
```

The above approach will not work for the surface view they will drawn as a hole in the screenshot.

**For surface view since Android 24, you need to use Pixel Copy**.

```
    /**
     * Pixel copy to copy SurfaceView/VideoView into BitMap
     */
     fun usePixelCopy(videoView: SurfaceView,  callback: (Bitmap?) -> Unit) {
        val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            videoView.width,
            videoView.height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        );
        try {
        // Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image.
        val handlerThread = HandlerThread("PixelCopier");
        handlerThread.start();
        PixelCopy.request(
            videoView, bitmap,
            PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener { copyResult ->
                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    callback(bitmap)
                }
                handlerThread.quitSafely();
            },
            Handler(handlerThread.looper)
        )
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            callback(null)
            // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

This approach can take a screenshot of any subclass of Surface Vie eg VideoView

```
Screenshot.usePixelCopy(videoView) { bitmap: Bitmap? ->
                processBitMap(bitmap)
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because SurfaceView uses OpenGL thread for drawing and draws directly to a hardware buffer. You have to use glReadPixels (and probably a GLWrapper).

See the thread: [Android OpenGL Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731589/android-opengl-screenshot)

Comment: Great Link. The Code in the Accepted answer seems to require this: GL10 gl where do I create this Object in my SurfaceView?

Comment: As I'm reading about your issue, I'm getting convinced that your method should work. There's a link about it on stackoverflow: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742868/android-creating-a-bitmap-with-surfaceview-content?lq=1
My method uses GLSurfaceView and a GLWrapper. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979069/creating-a-gl-texture-outside-of-glsurfaceview-renderer

Comment: Updated Code, see in the Question. It still isnt working right.

Comment: Rendering with a Canvas to a Surface is never hardware accelerated (as of 5.0), so attempting to capture pixels with GLES won't help.  Rendering to the View uses GLES if hardware acceleration is enabled, but the customary drawing-cache approach is more reliable.