# How to save GLSurfaceview render as obj file?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, google-project-tango

I am making an application on Project Tango tablet using eclipse. I am unable to get how to save GLSurfaceview render as obj file so that I can use that obj file in 3DSMax or Maya.

I have tried to save as png or jpeg but its saving a black image which is of no use.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen/

Comment: You're asking about how to generate an obj file which normally is used to carry 3D geometry and higher level structures, and then you're trying to take a picture to get it - unless you're just looking for a backdrop or a texture this just ain't gonna work -  if you want to get Tango 3D data into maya, you're going to need to do that yourself, GLSurfaceView can't help you - perhaps you could clarify the question ?