# Getting a frame from SurfaceView

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview

The difficulty I am having now is to take a screenshot of the SurfaceView. Could anyone please help?

My team is doing an Android project where we use MediaCodec to decode the video feed and render the feed onto a Surface.
The activity implements

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

Then we created a SurfaceView and add the Callback:

```
mySurfaveView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Then we start decode the video feed in (we have a method that does the decode)

```
surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
```

The video work fine, now I want to take screenshot of what gets rendered onto the SurfaceView. I have tried several ways to do this, but I didn't succeed. Following are what I have tried:

1. I have tired getting rootView's drawingcache.
2. Tried getting the frame directly from MediaCodec.
3. Tried the draw() method to draw on a canvas.

As of now I am tring to create a custom SurfaceView and override the onDraw method there. However, I have never created a custom SurfaceView. Am I on the right direction?

Help please. Thank you!

Comment: What you are trying to do is  explained very well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't capture a SurfaceView, as explained in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen).

SurfaceViews will rarely want to override `onDraw()`.  Generally the View part of the SurfaceView is a transparent hole.

For the specific case of MediaCodec output, you have a couple of choices.  You can direct the output to a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html), and then render the video frame twice using OpenGL ES.  Once to the SurfaceView for display, once to an off-screen buffer from which you can capture the pixels.

Another approach is to replace the SurfaceView with a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), and then use the `getBitmap()` call to grab video frames.

Various examples can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used a TextureView and it worked.

Comment: could you put the example code that how you replace `TextureView` with `surfaceView` ? the `MediaCodec.configure` function only get `SurfaceObject` as input and I have no idea how and where could I replace it with `TextureView`