# Android - Surface View ScreenShot

Tags: android, imageview, surfaceview

i have got screenshot code works fine with image, now i added surface view along with image. but takes shot with images and drawings. but doesn't take anything on surface view. please help me in this regard

here is screenshot code

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

       View rootView = null;
       rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
       rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       rootView.buildDrawingCache();
       rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }

     public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        File imagePath = new     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + new   SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss'.jpg'").format(new Date()) );
        FileOutputStream fos =null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            new   AlertDialog.Builder(DrawingActivity.this).setTitle("Info!").setMessage("New   Image Saved").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen/

Comment: @fadden i am struggling please help me.. thx