# can I force the surfaceview to freeze

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

One of my activities is a video recorder. When the user stops recording, I want the surfaceView to freeze. Is there a way to do this? And if so, can the freeze survive orientation change? I mean, for the "frame" (?) to remain the same after orientation.

Comment: What did you mean by "freeze" ? maybe you can draw a background or add a filter ?

Comment: By freeze I mean something like `surfaceView.getDrawingCache(true)`. But I am not really sure what to do with that method or how it might actually work. I want to capture the last feed as a bitmap and set it as the background of the SurfaceView overlay. This is just one possible implementation I am thinking of. (I am using a transparent overlay for buttons, etc)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/