# capturing image of multiple surfaceviews

Tags: android, image, surfaceview

I have two surfaces views in a frame layout, which also contains a linear layout with some buttons. One of the buttons should be able to capture and save an image of the two surfaceviews. One surfaceview is a camera preview and the other is an opengl surface with a square in it. How would you go about taking the picture and saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read data back from a SurfaceView Surface.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen).

The way that you "capture" it is by rendering it to something you *can* read the pixels from.  In your case, you'd grab a frame from the camera, render that to an offscreen pbuffer, then render the square with OpenGL ES onto the same pbuffer, and then grab that with `glReadPixels()`.  Essentially you perform the Surface composition yourself.