# Android : Taking Screenshot of all views on display

Tags: android, screenshot, android-bitmap, android-mediaprojection

I have a app with the following layout

- SurfaceHolder
- SurfaceView
- CameraPreview
- View (silly glasses)

All I want to do is take a picture / snapshot of this and looking into it, seem bonkers / complex

I first took a snapshot of the SurfaceView and got a black square, it appears this method is incorrect

Now I am using MediaProjection / ImageReader?

**Update** : So I do get a image but of wavy lines and it crashes because I am trying to stop the MediaProjection.  As said all I want to do is take a single picture

```
private void saveImage()
    {
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        final ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(cameraSurface.getWidth(), cameraSurface.getHeight(),  PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mProjection.createVirtualDisplay("screen-mirror", cameraSurface.getWidth(), cameraSurface.getHeight(), mScreenDensity, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, null);

        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = null;
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/myscreen.jpg");
                    final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    final Buffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer().rewind();
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraSurface.getWidth(), cameraSurface.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);

                    //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title" , "Desc");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (fos!=null) {
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    if (bitmap!=null)
                        bitmap.recycle();

                    if (image!=null)
                        image.close();

                    if (mProjection!=null) {
                        mProjection.stop();
                        mImageReader.close();

                    }
                }
            }

        }, mHandler);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're configuring your ImageReader for [ImageFormat.RGB_565](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RGB_565), which is format 0x4.  The virtual display is returning frames in format 0x1, [PixelFormat.RGBA_8888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#RGBA_8888).  (Yes, there are two overlapping definitions of color format.)  The configurations don't match, hence the error.

Change your ImageReader creation line to use the RGBA_8888 format instead.

You will have another issue when you try to create the Bitmap.  `decodeByteArray()` is meant for compressed data, such as PNG or JPEG.  It won't know how to interpret raw pixel data.  Use a call like [Bitmap#createBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) instead, passing ARGB_8888 in the [Bitmap.Config](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) parameter.

(For some more general commentary, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen).)