# getting a part of a Canvas as a Bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to get a part of `SurfaceView`'s canvas and save it as a `Bitmap`.
Every answer i've seen about it was creating a new `Canvas` and passing it your `Bitmap` to the constructor.

Because I am using `SurfaceView`, I am getting my canvas using the `SurfaceHodler` with `mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();` thus i can't creat a new `Canvas` with my `Bitmap`.

How can I get a part of my canvas to a `Bitmap` without crating a new canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Canvas is a rendering interface.  You can't get part of it, or all of it, because it's just the interface.  The pixels are drawn to a Bitmap or to the Surface, so if you want them you either have to read them back, or draw them again.

There's no way to retrieve pixels from a Surface -- it's the producer side of a producer-consumer pair.  The easiest thing to do is to repeat your drawing commands with a new Canvas that is backed by a Bitmap.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824250/294248).