# How to take screenshot from surfaceView in VLC

Tags: android, surfaceview, libvlc, surfaceholder, android-mediaprojection

I am playing streaming in vlc player and using surfaceView to show streaming, Now, i want to take screenshot of streaming at any time.

**Problem**
Now problem is that we can not take screenshot of SurfaceView. I also saw a sample of Media Projection but it's asking for permission every time. So on pause method of activity is called every time, Which should not be.

Can Any one help me on this, 
Is there any Xml tag which replace SurfaceView to take screenshot or we can remove the permission to capture screen using Media Projection.

Comment: This is something of an FAQ; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen/27824250#27824250