# Instabug screenshot with exoplayer shows blank screen

Tags: android, exoplayer, instabug

When take a screenshot from the exoplayer using Instabug bug reporting feature
it shows blank screen although the video is working fine

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: do you use SurfaceView?

Comment: @vezikon I didn't know the exoplayer default surface type is surfaceView 
the problem now fixed by changing  it to a texture view

Answer (score 3):

change surface type from **SurfaceView** to **TextureView**

```
 fun getScreenShotFromView(view: View, activity: Activity) {
    activity.window?.let { window ->
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val locationOfViewInWindow = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfViewInWindow)
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                PixelCopy.request(
                    window,
                    Rect(
                        locationOfViewInWindow[0],
                        locationOfViewInWindow[1],
                        locationOfViewInWindow[0] + view.width,
                        locationOfViewInWindow[1] + view.height
                    ), bitmap, { copyResult ->
                        if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                            callback(bitmap)                                
                        }
                    },
                    Handler()
                )
            }
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

call method as below

```
getScreenShotFromView(binding.root,requireActivity())
```

Answer (score 2):

Instabug doesn't support SurfaceView screenshot capturing at the time being, 
However, you can get the screenshot-capturing function work properly with the exoPlayer by changing the SurfaceType of the `PlayerView` to `Texture_view` instead of `SurfaceView`. You can do that using the following xml attribute.

`app:surface_type="texture_view"`

Answer (score 0):

This depends on many factors, one of them is the content of the video itself. 
Take a look at this bug https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1033

You can also try this [Android Take Screenshot of Surface View Shows Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen/27824250#27824250)

Comment: the screenshot works fine using the phone volume and power buttons.
the problem happens when done with instabug