# Record Screen / Take several screenshots of TextureView+other views

Tags: android, textureview, android-graphics, android-video-record

In a fragment I have a Texture View displaying the camera preview and on the top of that I draw several other views.

My goal is to record a short video of what the user sees (all views) or save several screenshots to compile later into a video.

Since I don't want any disclaimer to show up and Intent associated, I don't want to use MediaProjection.

I've tried many things but all either don't work or take screenshot/record all views except for the TextureView, which turns out black in the outcome. Note that I don't wish to use MediaRecorder either because it'll only allow me to record the textureview and I want all of the contents to be recorded/screenshot.

I understand that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824250/9157490) is the reason TextureView comes out black.

I have actually managed to get screenshots with the PixelCopy api, particularly [this call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy#request(android.view.Window,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.view.PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener,%20android.os.Handler)), but minimum sdk version is 26 and I needed a solution to work for minimum 24 sdk version, otherwise it would be an option for me... Also, the ideal scenario would be getting a video and not the frames for later making the video.

So, can anyone point out the better way of doing this? I'm currently not seeing any alternatives...

Again, I want to give the user a small video of the entire screen display (all views).

Thanks a lot in advance!